# what is programming meaning of that expression in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, expression

what is programming meaning of that expression in ASP.net?

```
List<int> productsInCart = (List<int>)Session["cart"];
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is `creating` a list of type int, from existing list object which is in Session with `key cart` that is type cast to `list<int>` before assignment.

- `Session["cart"]` Session is a collection that holds object, `Session["cart"]` hold object with key name cart.
- `(List<int>)` is used to type cast the object in returned by `Session["cart"]`
- `List<int> productsInCart` created object of type `List<int>`

Comment: then we have a list of session["cart"] with the name productInCart

Comment: For session collection it is object, you can store objects in it, could be list, array, object of some class or simply a string. You assigned the object retrieved from Session["Cart"], its upto you what you store it Session, but it is for sure you will get what you will store.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an `ASP.NET` syntax, but `C#` one.

`Session` looks to be an associative array whose index is of type `string`. `["cart"]` is indexing, i.e. accessing array element by it's index or "address", which here is of type `string`. May be you know better a term "key-value storage", not an "associative array". The terms mean the same.

Although index type is well defined for Session, it's content type looks to be defined as `object`, i.e. a type, which can hold object of any type.

`List<int> productsInCart` is a definition of variable of name `productsInCart` and of type `List<int>`. This type means variable contains a list (i.e. non-fixed length array) of integer values. Probably these values are ids of goods.

`(List<int>)` is type cast which in `C#` means just a check, that an `object` which was retrived from `Session` array, is actually of type `List<int>`.

In `C#` any subtype can be assigned to supertype variable without check. For example, `List<int>` variable can be assigned to `object`. This is always possible and requires no casting. Reverse assignment is not alway possible. Only those `onject`s can be assigned to `List<int>` variable, who actually have this type. So explicit type cast is required wich will serve as an exception source if type will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
  (List<int>)
```

is type-casting. That means it is converting

```
  Session["cart"]
```

into the list of integer type and saving that list in the productInCart list.